# Use LogLevels in Monolog (Symfony)

Tags: php, logging, symfony4, monolog

coming from Java development, I learned to appreciate LogLevel, how to set it in Logback or Log4j.

Monolog is used in my symphony 4.2 project.

I would like to see that from a certain controller/namespace the log entries with level info can also be seen in the production log file without all the other log entries with the info level filling the log file.

Unfortunately I didn't find any explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more research, I configured my monolog.yaml for dev and also prod this way

```
monolog:
  channels: ['appinfo']
  handlers:
    custom:
      channels: ['appinfo']
      level: info
      max_files: 30
      path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/appinfo.log"
      type: rotating_file
```

The important thing is the channel, **appinfo** in my case.

The handler, **custom** in my case, can be named any way you like.

Then in the services.yaml one has to define the "type" of the injected logger.

```
App\Controller\DefaultController:
  arguments:
    $logger: '@monolog.logger.appinfo'
```

This works with controllers as with services